# Wired dot in header of appendix

Tags: appendices

i created an appendix using this snippet

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
  \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}
\makeatother
  \chapter{Code Listings}
  \input{anhang_code.tex}

  \chapter{Survey Questions}
  \input{anhang_survey.tex}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}
```

However, the header on the appendix pages contain a wired dot

[image]

How can i get rid of this dot?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your example a [complete but minimal document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that can be used to reproduce the result you get?